# How to get response from webmethod and pass sql parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax script calling a web method same way like I do ever but now,  cant get response. I got parse error. Please help.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void UzmiTaskove(int idprojekta)
{
        List<Taskovi> listataskova = new List<Taskovi>();
        string CS = Properties.Settings.Default.Konekcija.ToString();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("UzmiTaskove", con);
            cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();

            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProj", idprojekta);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Taskovi tas = new Taskovi();
                tas.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
                tas.IdProjekta = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["IdProjekta"]);
                tas.Opis = rdr["Opis"].ToString();
                tas.DatumPocetka = rdr["DatumPocetka"].ToString();
                tas.DatumZavrsetka = rdr["DatumZavrsetka"].ToString();
                tas.Status = rdr["Status"].ToString();

                listataskova.Add(tas);
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer jm = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(jm.Serialize(listataskova));
}

$.ajax({
        url: 'TaskoviServis.asmx/UzmiTaskove',
        type: 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({ idprojekta:idprojekta}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (respons) {
            alert(respons.d);

            var newHtml = "";
            $(poda).each(function (index, tas) {

                newHtml += '<li class="task">';
                newHtml += '<div class="task-container">';
                newHtml += '<span class="task-action-btn task-check">';
                newHtml += '<span class="action-circle large complete-btn" title="Mark Complete">';
                newHtml += '<i class="material-icons">check</i>';
                newHtml += '</span>';
                newHtml += '</span>';
                newHtml += '<span class="task-label" contenteditable="true">' + tas.Opis + '</span>';
                newHtml += '<span class="task-action-btn task-btn-right">';
                newHtml += '<span class="action-circle large" title="Assign">';
                newHtml += '<i class="material-icons">person_add</i>';
                newHtml += '</span>';
                newHtml += '<span class="action-circle large delete-btn" title="Delete Task">';
                newHtml += '<i class="material-icons">delete</i>';
                newHtml += '</span>';
                newHtml += '</span>';
                newHtml += '</div>';
                newHtml += '</li>';
            });

            $("#task-list").append(newHtml);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

I tried everything.. change datatype.. and etc...

Comment: Q: Have you looked at your Ajax request in Chrome Developer Tools?  Did the JSON look OK?  ALSO: please copy/paste the exact error message in to your question.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer
This is the answer from AJAX call in chrome debuger
OK
Taskovi.js:84 parsererror
Taskovi.js:85 SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 264
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Qb (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so got your problem this method giving problem bcose its void, so change nothing in the ajax code your ajax code is fine just change the webmethod code make return type and return value directly instead of response.write try below code.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Taskovi> UzmiTaskove(int idprojekta)
{
        List<Taskovi> listataskova = new List<Taskovi>();
        string CS = Properties.Settings.Default.Konekcija.ToString();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("UzmiTaskove", con);
            cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();

            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProj", idprojekta);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Taskovi tas = new Taskovi();
                tas.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
                tas.IdProjekta = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["IdProjekta"]);
                tas.Opis = rdr["Opis"].ToString();
                tas.DatumPocetka = rdr["DatumPocetka"].ToString();
                tas.DatumZavrsetka = rdr["DatumZavrsetka"].ToString();
                tas.Status = rdr["Status"].ToString();

                listataskova.Add(tas);
            }
        }

       // JavaScriptSerializer jm = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      //  Context.Response.Write(jm.Serialize(listataskova));
      return listataskova;
}
```

and in the ajax make changes like below

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'TaskoviServis.asmx/UzmiTaskove',
    type: 'POST',
    data:JSON.stringify({ idprojekta:idprojekta}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (respons) {
        //alert(respons.d);
        console.log(respons.d)
        var newHtml = "";
        $(respons.d).each(function (index, tas) {

            newHtml += '<li class="task">';
            newHtml += '<div class="task-container">';
            newHtml += '<span class="task-action-btn task-check">';
            newHtml += '<span class="action-circle large complete-btn" title="Mark Complete">';
            newHtml += '<i class="material-icons">check</i>';
            newHtml += '</span>';
            newHtml += '</span>';
            newHtml += '<span class="task-label" contenteditable="true">' + tas.Opis + '</span>';
            newHtml += '<span class="task-action-btn task-btn-right">';
            newHtml += '<span class="action-circle large" title="Assign">';
            newHtml += '<i class="material-icons">person_add</i>';
            newHtml += '</span>';
            newHtml += '<span class="action-circle large delete-btn" title="Delete Task">';
            newHtml += '<i class="material-icons">delete</i>';
            newHtml += '</span>';
            newHtml += '</span>';
            newHtml += '</div>';
            newHtml += '</li>';
        });

        $("#task-list").append(newHtml);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

try this should work.

Comment: Thanks...Now I have error ..Invalid Web Service Call..missing parameter idprojekta..????

Comment: make sure [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] this line is uncommented.

Comment: @CristianoAzarnowski try this

Comment: respond text : "[{\"ID\":1,\"IdProjekta\":2244,\"Opis\":\"Lorem Ipsum Dolores\",\"DatumPocetka\":\"25/06/2019\",\"DatumZavrsetka\":\"25/07/2019\",\]{\"d\":null}"

Comment: if you got this response in the success callback than it's working, there can be problem in you .each loop.

Comment: i have edited answer now check it, this should work